# Copying and changing name of files in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, directory, file-copying

I have a directory called as **"ID"** which has multiple sub-directories like **"12","2","30","24"** etc. each Sub-directory again have sub-directory inside it like for instance **12** has sub-directories inside it named **"1port_50","1port_60","1port_80","3port_100","log","root"**.

Now again these sub directory "1port_50"  have multiple image(.jpg) files inside them named as **"xyz_2018.jpg,  pqd_201.jpg"** and "**1port_60**" has **foo_174.jpg, bar_142.jpg, foobar_73.jpg** and so on. except for the directory **"log","root"**(these two folder contains nothing and id to be discarded).

What I want to do is

1)Go inside directory **"12"** and count number of occurrence of each type of port

2)go inside each "port" directory file like inside **"1port_50"** and check for number of image files

3)Create a directory called as "1port_1" at other location say for instance "**D:/Files/1port_1**" and copy all the image files which was inside **1port_abc** folder and rename those image files to **xyz_1.jpg, pqd_2.jpg**(because the only two images thats why *_1 and *_2)

4)Again go inside directory **"1port_60"** check number of image files, create another folder "1port_2" at location "**D:/Files/**" and rename the image files **foo_1.jpg, bar_2.jpg, foobar_3.jpg** (since there are 3 .jpg files inside 1port_60 so renaming them to *_1,*_2,*_3.)

5)Repeat the same process for all directories inside "**ID**" directory.
Here is the code I tried but not got through

SO  finallly the the directory should look like this.

```
  D->Files->1port_1->xyz_1.jpg, pqd_2.jpg
  D->Files->1port_2->foo_1.jpg, bar_2.jpg, foobar_3.jpg
  D->Files->1port_3->ab_1.jpg, aar_2.jpg, qerr_3.jpg
  D->Files->3port_1->poi_1.jpg
```

---

```
import os
folder_list =os.listdir("D:/ID")
folder_list_prev = [e for e in folder_list if e not in ('log','root')]
folder_list = [x.rsplit('_',1)[0] for x in folder_list_prev]
distElementList=list(set(folder_list))
ty=[]
freq=[]

for v,k in Counter(folder_list).items():
  ty.append(v)
  freq.append(k)

for i in range(0,len(folder_list_prev)):
  for n in range(0,len(freq)):
    for m in range(1,freq[n]+2):
      os.makedirs(("D:\\Files\\"+folder_list_prev[m-1].split('_')[0]+"_"+str(m)))
      img_inside_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(('D:/ID/12'+folder_list_prev[m-1])) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

      for j in range(0,len(img_inside_dir)):
        copyfile('D:/ID/12'+folder_list_prev[m-1]+'/'+img_inside_dir[j],'D:Files/'+folder_list_prev[m-1].split('_')[0]+'_'+str(m)+'/'+img_inside_dir[j])
```

Here I tried to do only for One ID i.e for **12**.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved.

Comment: You should really look into `os.walk()`. Docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the logic in your naming convention for the new directory in which you want to ultimately store your images, but here's an example of how to use [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). You'll have to implement the rest of the logic to fit your needs.

```
import os

start_dir = "/Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID"

all_image_files = []
"""
all_image_files is a list of objects representing each image file on the following format:
{
    "parent_directory": path_to_parent_directory,
    "image_filename": name of image file
}
"""
print "Finding image files."
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_dir):
    # Find image files
    image_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith(".jpg")]
    if len(image_files) == 0:
        print "No image files in the current directory (%s)" % root
    else:
        print "Found image files in %s: %s" % (root, image_files)
        # Loop through images and save them to the all_image_files list
        for i in image_files:
            all_image_files.append({
                "parent_directory": root,
                "image_filename": i
            })

# Now you can do whatever logit it is that you need.
# I didn't quite understand what you wanted, so this
# just prints the objects.
print "\n====== Images found ======"
for image_object in all_image_files:
    print "Parent directory:", image_object["parent_directory"]
    print "Image filename:", image_object["image_filename"]
    print "Full path to image:", os.path.join(image_object["parent_directory"], image_object["image_filename"])
    print "--------------------------------------------------"
```

This prints, with my example directory structure, this:

```
Finding image files.
No image files in the current directory (/Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID)
No image files in the current directory (/Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12)
Found image files in /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50: ['hello2.jpg', 'hello3.jpg', 'hello.jpg']
Found image files in /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60: ['hello2.jpg', 'hello3.jpg', 'hello1.jpg']
Found image files in /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_70: ['hello1.jpg']
No image files in the current directory (/Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2)
Found image files in /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100: ['hello2.jpg', 'hello3.jpg', 'hello1.jpg']

====== Images found ======
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50
Image filename: hello2.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50/hello2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50
Image filename: hello3.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50/hello3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50
Image filename: hello.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_50/hello.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60
Image filename: hello2.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60/hello2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60
Image filename: hello3.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60/hello3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60
Image filename: hello1.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_60/hello1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_70
Image filename: hello1.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/12/1port_70/hello1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100
Image filename: hello2.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100/hello2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100
Image filename: hello3.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100/hello3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
Parent directory: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100
Image filename: hello1.jpg
Full path to image: /Users/jonas/testing/port_test/ID/2/1port_100/hello1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------
```